# ExecutionCriteria: Package unavailable for Task

Tags: android, android-studio

What is the meaning of this errors?
Showing this error multiple time in LogCat.
Why there PayTM, MyJio and Travelkhana Package names?

```
2018-11-05 19:23:10.056 31694-31726/? E/ExecutionCriteria: Package unavailable for task: com.travelkhana/com.firebase.jobdispatcher.GooglePlayReceiver{u=0 tag="db-tag" trigger=window{start=0s,end=10s,earliest=-20731036s,latest=-20731026s} requirements=[NET_CONNECTED] attributes=[PERSISTED] scheduled=-20731036s last_run=N/A jid=N/A status=PENDING retries=0 client_lib=FIREBASE_JOB_DISPATCHER-1}
2018-11-05 19:23:10.061 31694-31726/? E/ExecutionCriteria: Package unavailable for task: net.one97.paytm/com.firebase.jobdispatcher.GooglePlayReceiver{u=10 tag="SDK_UPLOAD+1" trigger=window{start=172800s,end=259200s,earliest=-12476877s,latest=-12390477s} requirements=[NET_UNMETERED,CHARGING] attributes=[PERSISTED,RECURRING] scheduled=-12649677s last_run=N/A jid=N/A status=PENDING retries=0 client_lib=FIREBASE_JOB_DISPATCHER-1}
2018-11-05 19:23:10.063 31694-31726/? E/ExecutionCriteria: Package unavailable for task: com.jio.myjio/com.bb.lib.scheduler.service.MobileWifiDataUsageTaskService{u=10 tag="periodicTask" trigger=window{period=3600s,flex=60s,earliest=-9496592s,latest=-9496412s} requirements=[NET_CONNECTED] attributes=[PERSISTED,RECURRING] scheduled=-9500012s last_run=N/A jid=N/A status=PENDING retries=0 client_lib=MANCHEGO_GCM-12211000}
2018-11-05 19:23:10.064 31694-31726/? E/ExecutionCriteria: Package unavailable for task: com.jio.myjio/com.bb.lib.scheduler.service.MeasureDataUsageTaskService{u=10 tag="periodicTask" trigger=window{period=3600s,flex=60s,earliest=-9496591s,latest=-9496411s} requirements=[NET_CONNECTED] attributes=[PERSISTED,RECURRING] scheduled=-9500011s last_run=N/A jid=N/A status=PENDING retries=0 client_lib=MANCHEGO_GCM-12211000}
2018-11-05 19:23:10.065 31694-31726/? E/ExecutionCriteria: Package unavailable for task: com.jio.myjio/com.bb.lib.scheduler.service.ScheduleInitializerTaskService{u=10 tag="periodicTask" trigger=window{period=86460s,flex=60s,earliest=-9456928s,latest=-9452605s} requirements=[NET_CONNECTED] attributes=[PERSISTED,RECURRING] scheduled=-9539065s last_run=N/A jid=N/A status=PENDING retries=0 client_lib=MANCHEGO_GCM-12211000}
2018-11-05 19:23:10.065 31694-31726/? E/ExecutionCriteria: Package unavailable for task: com.jio.myjio/com.bb.lib.scheduler.service.SimWiseSMSPushTaskService{u=10 tag="periodicTask" trigger=window{period=259200s,flex=60s,earliest=-9292760s,latest=-9279800s} requirements=[NET_CONNECTED] attributes=[PERSISTED,RECURRING] scheduled=-9539000s last_run=N/A jid=N/A status=PENDING retries=0 client_lib=MANCHEGO_GCM-12211000}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found simlar strange logs on my logcat. Was like:

> Package unavailable for task:
>   com.upwork.android/.tasksDispatcher.TasksDispatcher

Some time ago  I've installed the app `upwork`, but removed it afterwards.

Now I installed the app again, and the error was gone... then I removed this app again, and  the error is still gone.

Maybe the deinstallation-process finishd with a fully deinstalled app... so you also might give it a try to reinstall those apps you got an error (in your case: travelkhana, paytm, myjio) msg in logcat, and remove them again.

Good luck!